# Can MySQL handle large amounts of data?

Tags: php, mysql

I a developing college management web application with PHP and MySQL. I chose MySQL as my database because of its free license. Will it handle large amounts of data? College datas gradually increases with more schools and number of years the datas are accumulated. Is MySQL the best one for large amount of datas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're looking for 'the best one', you will never find it.

Comment: large- Total college management datas which includes attendance, marks, library, book keeping etc.

Comment: MySQL can be used for some seriously large datasets (100s of tables containing billions of rows).... somehow, while your college data will increase over time, I think it highly unlikely that it will reach seriously large this century (even with predicted population growth). Now if you were talking global banking transactions over a score of years, that would be seriously large

Comment: One college? That's not large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is definitely the best choice for you to start, as it is...

- free available
- a defacto standard in combination with PHP
- a good start for beginners
- and yes, can handle a huge amount of data

I've seen lots of companies and startups, which are using MySQL and handling tons of data. If you ran into performance issues later, you can care about it then, e.g. use a caching layer, optimize MySQL, etc.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL is perfectly fine; facebook uses mySQL for instance; I can't imagine a database size more extensive... see https://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=7899307130 from facebooks blog.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will handle large amounts of data just fine, making sure your tables are properly indexed is going to go along way into ensuring that you can retrieve large data sets in a timely manner.  We have a client that has a database with over 5 million records, and don't have much trouble outside the normal issues in dealing with a table that large.

Each flavor of SQL has it's own differences, just make sure you do your due diligence to find out the best options for your database and tables based on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Table size has a max of 4GB by default, you can change this. PostgresSQL, you set the limit when you create a table.

Comment: Not true. The limit depends on max file size the filesystem allows. 4GB is the limit for FAT32. Any mdern filesystem can support filesizes in order of terabytes.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql is OK choice, bit if you're expecting vast amounst of data I would prefer postgres sql (imho best free db avaliable).

Comment: Why would you prefer it over MySQL? Just name it isn't a helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i started my application with mysql.